# Locker Service With Inner html tag issue

Tags: lightning, locker-service, html5

I have below code where i am trying to display data in a table format based the html element stored in a field.

```
<table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer">
    <thead aura:id="t1"></thead>
    <tbody aura:id="t2"></tbody>
</table>

var t1 = component.find("t1");
var t2 = component.find("t2");
var thead= '', tbody= '';
for (var i = 0, listLength = tableRowList.length; i < listLength; i++) {
    if (tableRowList[i].IsHeader__c) {
        thead=thead+tableRowList[i].Row__c;
    } else {
        tbody=tbody+tableRowList[i].Row__c;
    }
}
t1.getElement().innerHTML += thead;
t2.getElement().innerHTML += tbody;
console.log('@@@@',t1.getElement().innerHTML);
```

With locker service enabled org, the innerHtml tag is removing the html elements in the data and trying to display the text value.

Any solution for above problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this works:

```
$A.createComponent("aura:html", {"tag":"th", "body":"My Header", "HTMLAttributes":{"id":"myFirstTH"}},
            function(newCmp, status) {
                // Push newCmp to v.body of existing component
                var t1 = component.find("t1");
                t1.set("v.body",newCmp);
            }
        );
```

Although if you have HTML elements in the body it gets more complicated but this will add the TH element to the t1 element as an example

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but i have to display html elements dynamically. i.e html code will be present in some field, i need to fetch that field and display then in aura.
Example field may contain value in this form <tr> <th>Test Column 1</th> <th>Test Column 2</th> <th>Test Column 3</th> <th>Test Column 4</th> <th>Test Column 5</th> </tr> <tr> <td>Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem</td> <td>Ipsum Lorem</td> <td>Test Test</td> <td><b>Bold text example</b></td> <td>Test </td> </tr>

This value should render as html table in aura

Comment: And you generate the component based off that field. Or use aura:HTML

Comment: In the 1st example , thead and tbody has that value. How could i use it in aura:Html? I am not getting to put it in aura:Html.